# Are questions on collaboration processes appropriate?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I want to ask a question along the lines of "How to find and collaborate with an illustrator for a comic series as a writer", would that be on topic here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, yes.

From a quick search you can see a number of (relatively) similar questions:

- [How to find long-term clients?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/77101/52050)
- [Where can I find web design projects?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/27525/52050)
- [How can I find an illustrator who can produce game art in a particular style?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/47328/52050)
- [How to find a professional designer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/46250/52050)
- [How can I find a mentor to critique my work?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/40958/52050)

I will say that to me it sounds as if it may be too broad a question for a Stack Exchange Q&A, but that depends on how you pose the question. The subject matter is certainly on-topic it just may not be a *good* question. Stack Exchange prefers questions that can be objectively answered, which this probably can't be.

If you do ask your question, make sure to follow the guidelines in [help/how-to-ask](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask); be specific, give as much context and detail as you can and try to make the question relevant and useful  to future readers and you should hopefully be OK.